# Have Kit Fisto and Qui-Gon Jinn ever fought/duelled?

Tags: star-wars

Qui-Gon Jinn and Kit Fisto are 2 of my favorite characters from Star Wars and I was wondering which one of them is better at lightsaber combat.

I know that Kit Fisto is one of the three Jedi that Mace Windu chose to help him arrest Palpatine. Qui-Gon however was also a very powerful Jedi and was trained by Count Dooku, no doubt he learned some tricks from him.

**Have they ever fought (or duelled) in any canon, and if so, who won?**

Comment: How is it opinion if they've ever dueled or not? Come on, people.

Comment: They've never dueled, not surprisingly, since they are both Jedi.

Comment: Perhaps not with deadly intentions, but I imagine Jedi spar with each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the attractive [Star Wars Top Trumps I-III](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Top_Trumps:_Star_Wars_Episodes_I-III) cards below, Kit Fisto's "battle skill" (which presumably includes his prowess with the lightsaber) is higher than Qui-Gon Jinn's.

[image: Kit Fitso card showing Jedi Powers at 81 and Battle Skills at 44, Qui-Gon's shows Jedi Powers at 65 and Battle Skills at 41]

Comment: Top Trumps cards are, of course, super-canon, over-riding even the films.

Comment: @evilsoup - Well obviously. Duh. Everyone knows that. Even George Lucas agrees; http://i.stack.imgur.com/6li2g.jpg

Comment: How much dark side points a Sith has?

Comment: @SachinShekhar; http://www.tradingcarddb.com/Images/Cards/Non-Sport/89012/89012-6360737Fr.jpg, http://www.tradingcarddb.com/Images/Cards/Non-Sport/89012/89012-6360736Fr.jpg, http://www.tradingcarddb.com/Images/Cards/Non-Sport/89012/89012-6360734Fr.jpg

Comment: Darth Maul has more Dark Side points than Palpatine?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Yes.

Comment: Lol Palpatine's card sucks.

Comment: How did Top Trump come up with these numbers? A random number generator?

Comment: Also, as much as I actually like this answer, and think it is by far the closest the QA will get to an answer - Jedi tend not to fight each other - it doesn't actually answer the question. As I said, it's still the closest the QA is likely to get, so I'm hardly about to flag the thing.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - per wikipedia; "the aim of the game is to compare these values to try to trump and win an opponent's card" - If that's not another way of saying "duelling", I don't know what it is...

Comment: @Richard: Yeah, but it's not the same as them actually fighting in the *EU* material. Still, as I said, it's as close as the QA is going to get, so I have no problem with it.

Comment: While this is probably the best answer the QA is going to get, Top Trump cards are a terrible reference source.  I don't know how they came up with their numbers, but it wasn't by carefully examining the source material.  Back when I played with these cards I remember noticing all sorts of errors.

Comment: @numaroth - As evildoers said, Top Trump cards are considered super - canon, even above the films and interviews with the Director.

Comment: @Richard Since I can't tell your tone through text, I can't tell if you're joking or genuinely trying to correct me.  I assumed that evilsoup was joking

Comment: @numaroth - lol. This answer (and my comments) are firmly tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @Richard Glad to know that I was right about your comment, but I feel a bit silly because I totally misread the tone of your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Qui-Gon Jinn and Kit Fisto did not have any recorded sparring sessions known to us, so we do not know the results. The only alternative is to compare their performance against common opponents. Both went up against a Sith Lord knowing what they're up against. You can see they are both very dead.

We use three separate battles in our analysis:

1. Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan fought the Sith Apprentice Darth Maul in an extended battle, but when Obi-Wan was isolated from the fight, Qui-Gon was struck down within a few minutes.
2. Mace Windu, Kit Fisto and two other Jedi attempted to arrest Supreme Chancellor Palpatine, now revealed to them as the Sith Master Darth Sidious. The two Jedi are inconsequential, both dead the moment Palpatine drew his blade, but Kit Fisto managed to hold his own for maybe 5-15 seconds before dying too.
3. Darth Sidious went to deal with his ex-apprentice Maul - whose presence is a disruption to the Rule of Two and an interference with Sidious' plans - and fought both Maul and his brother-apprentice Savage Opress. Opress died and Maul was captured with little contest, but still more challenging than the previous two fights.

We compare Maul to Fisto via Sidious, then compare Fisto to Qui-Gon via Maul. The points we can draw from the above fights are:

- Maul is strong, but not that strong: He may be uncertain of victory against two Jedi, especially two bonded as master and student, thus resorting to tactics to create a divide and conquer approach, as he is much more confident against them individually. He only lost to Obi-Wan due to overconfidence and arrogance at the end, wasting time on gloating, giving Obi-Wan time to escape death and turn the tables.
- That means Qui-Gon on his own is probably out-matched by Maul all along. He only held out for so long because Obi-Wan was there to better the odds.
- Maul is probably more skilled than Kit Fisto, judging by how long he survived not being defeated by Sidious.
- Sidious is likely holding back in the fight with Windu. He quickly dispatched everyone, but kept Windu alive because he wanted to use him as the bait and sacrifice to turn Anakin to the dark side. In any case, Kit Fisto never stood a chance.
- Sidious may also be holding back against Maul. We now know in canon that Sidious was deliberately keeping Maul alive for other plans, so he fought differently since he wanted Maul alive and in one piece. If he had went all out, it's very possible Maul wouldn't have lasted so long.

In conclusion: **We do not know.** As said, we compared Maul to Fisto via Sidious, then compared Fisto to Qui-Gon via Maul. However, it is likely Sidious has been holding back all along, so any observations made are unlikely to be accurate. We are pretty sure Sidious went all out against Yoda, but we have no available sources to do the same analysis with Yoda replacing Maul's place in the process.

Assuming Sidious wasn't holding back? Maul lasted longer alone against Sidious than Kit Fisto against Sidious when Sidious was focused on Mace Windu, while Qui-Gon Jinn lasted longer alone against Maul than Kit Fisto against Sidious when Sidious was focused on Mace Windu. I guess that suggests **Qui-Gon Jinn is statistically better**.

Answer (score 0):

Fisto would win. Fisto was highly advanced in spirit, force and sabreskills and was also physically strong and had great fighting stamina- still young for a nautolan at 45. His tentacles can sense change in chemical signature, his style of fighting was jar'kai fencing, splashes of ataru movements but overwhelmingly an unexplored, unorthodox usage of shii cho- wild, blitzing, immersive and dangerous, chaotic, unpredictable and unfamiliar to all adversaries when fully mastered and pushed to the furthest degree.. not to mention fisto is cunning, a master of improvisation, by the time of his death, the jedi council member was a galactic hero and decorated, battle-hardened high general of the clone war.
Though he didn't last long against sidious, it's important to note that sidious wanted him dead and out of the way immediately without having to have a long fight, and with maul vs obi and qui gon, that was a different fight in which maul was eager for a drawn out fight and to, for lack of a better expression, play with his food.. He was arrogant and wanted to show off his skills, so he kept qui gon alive until he got bored. This is all while maul is sidious's inferior and dooku's superior (contentious statement but one i believe nonetheless which is also backed by the trump cards).
So what do we have, we have qui gon who is on the other side of 60, gets tired if he exerts himself too long and starts to lose his game with anything exceeding short bursts of action, his force abilities extending mainly to his surroundings.. While other jedi use the force to for themselves and try to harness and control it, qui gon lets the force use him in a very pacifist, spiritually connected way where he accepts that he's simply a small cog in a bigger plan. Qui gon sacrifices his potential to use the force in life to be powerful, so he can uncover hidden secrets and become powerful after death. In the meantime while alive, qui gon only knows the bare essentials like affect mind and object manipulation and some telekinesis, just enough to pass as satisfactory for success in jedi ranks while the rest is focused on letting the force guide him, recieve rather than transmit. Qui gon studied lightsaber style soresu to block blasterfire and have well rounded defensiveness against blasterfire and strikes, while incorporating bare elements from ataru as a more proactive approach against force sensitive, unique assailants.
So i think force wise, natural gift wise, physicality wise and fighting wise, kit is the superior master.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! So you're saying that Fisto and Jinn never fought/sparred (which is the question) but that if they had Fisto would have won? Please make this more clear and please [edit] your post to include proper capitalization, grammar, paragraph spacing, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Lightsaber combat does not only mean Physical one to one combat. It also includes other forms of combat, such as the power of the Force within a Jedi or a Sith, especially in lightsaber combats. Theoretically, a Jedi or a Sith may utilise the Force in order to "see" into the future and predict the opponent's move before he makes it. As Qui-Gon is much more trained in the the arts of the Force, but Kit Fisto is much better in terms of combat arts, when it comes to a one-to-one battle, there is a higher possibility that Kit may win the battle despite the fact that he is not as good as Qui-Gon in terms of the arts of the Force.
However, the result may differ if Qui-Gon manages to utilise the Force well in order to defeat Kit Fisto (not saying they will ever fight against each other). It also depends on what kind of environment they are fighting in.
Overall, I would say that we would never know as nobody here is a Jedi or a Sith (for Sith, it may also differ from Jedi's).

Comment: Sooo...your answer is "I don't know"?

Comment: @Monty129 - It certainly seemed like a fancy way of saying "I don't know" :-)

Comment: I'm saying that it always depends on situations

Answer (score -2):

I think Qui-Gon would win. I've watched the movies over and over and it doesn't even look like Kit Fisto put up a fight, at least Qui-Gon did.

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. Other than the fact that Kit Fisto got shot in the back, what other evidence can you offer?